# Equivalent eip/rip, ebp/rpb, UESP/rsp registers for ARM / Aarchh64 processor

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, eip, program-counter

### Heading ##What is the equivalent of **eip**, **rip** registers used for Intel CPU but for ARM/Aaarch64 CPU ?

I need to translate a application written for Intel CPU that uses the 32 bit **eip** or the 64 bit **rip** register.

Thoses methods use intel registers:

function GetInstructionPointerRegisterValue
--> uses: regs32[eip] or regs64[rip].

function GetStackBasePointerRegisterValue
--> uses: regs32[ebp] or regs64[rbp]

function GetStackPointerRegisterValue
--> uses: regs32[UESP] or regs64[rsp].

What similar register should I use for ARM ARM/Aaarch64 ?

And does it exist a table with comparison and equivalence of the x86/amd64 registers vs the registers of arm/aarch64 ?

Thanks.

Comment: The register is called `PC` but it is not a general purpose register.  Note that being separate architectures, there is not really a 1:1 correspondence between x86 and AArch64 registers.  You can use any assignment between the x86 registers and the 31 general purpose registers you want, though `SP` should stay `SP`.  If you can show me what you are trying to do, perhaps I could be able to provide more directed help.

Comment: ARM has a PC-relative addressing mode with limited range.  I assume AArch64 does, too, but it also has `adrp` and so on for generating PC-relative addresses into another register, like x86-64 RIP-relative LEA.

Comment: @fuz : Thanks, I will try with PC.  
It is for a Pascal fpc debugger program that works for x86-64 and that needs to access the cpu via asm registers.
For example: function GetInstructionPointerRegisterValue uses: regs32[eip] or regs64[rip]. 
GetStackBasePointerRegisterValue uses: regs32[ebp] or regs64[rbp].
GetStackPointerRegisterValue uses: regs32[UESP] or regs64[rsp].

Comment: @ Peter: ok I will try too with adrp.  Write you later

Answer (score 1):

The program counter on ARM/AArch64 is called PC.

ARM has a PC-relative addressing mode with limited range.  I assume AArch64 does, too, but it also has `adrp` and so on for generating PC-relative addresses into another register, like x86-64 RIP-relative LEA.

ARM and AArch64 don't have many/any instructions that implicitly use any specific general-purpose register other than the stack pointer, so the "equivalence table" with x86-64 would be very short.  Unlike x86 `shl r/m, cl` for example, you don't need a value in a specific register to shift by it, more like x86 BMI2 `shlx reg, reg/mem, reg` but without the CISC ability to use a memory source.  ARM and AArch64 picked a more orthogonal design to start with instead of having lots of implicit uses for different registers like x86 did to allow shorter instructions with x86's variable-length instruction encoding.

Comment: I will do it then step by step.

Comment: Aaargh, that enter... So I said I will do it step by step. The most needed for now is to find equivalence for eip/rip.  I will try with pc and adrp.  The 2 other steps are for equivalence with ebp/rbp and with UESP/rsp.  If you have a idea: welcome ;-).  I hope with those 3 methods, I can go far.  Many thanks.

Comment: @fredvs: PC is the equivalent of RIP.  Did you actually want an equivalent for some *usage* of RIP?  Look at compiler output, especially optimized compiler output for a non-leaf function should do some push/pop equivalent stuff, like AArch64 `ldp`/`stp` with a pre-decrement (`[sp, -32]!`) or post-increment addressing mode (`[sp], 32`).  Or ARM `stm` / `ldm`.  Or to see it set up a frame pointer, use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.  https://godbolt.org/z/sbT7jKa65  Or for PC-relative, access a global var, maybe with `-fPIE` to force PC-relative but not GOT.

Comment: No it is more simpler ( but complicated also ).  In a Pascal program, there are some asm access to intel cpu.

Comment: @fredvs: Then ask about that in your question, not some general abstract thing if you don't want to know about the general stuff.

Comment: Pff that enter key...  So there are 3 methods.  The first uses RIP and thanks to you I get it, it is PC.  The second method uses rbp but I dont know the equivalent for Aarch64.  And the 3th uses rsp that I need the translation too.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will complete my question. ( I am surprised by the quality and speed of answers)

Comment: @ Peter: A contrario, I am very interested by your comments, all that is very new for me and so happy because of your help.

Answer (score 1):

[aarch64](/questions/tagged/aarch64)

The AArch64 equivalent of the x86 instruction pointer is the program counter register, `pc`.  Unlike on ARM32, `pc` is not a general-purpose register and cannot be used with ordinary instructions like `mov`.  However, if you need its "current value", i.e. the address of the current instruction (or the next one, whichever you prefer), you can do this with the `adr` instruction, which returns the value of `pc` plus an immediate offset.  (`adrp` here would only get you the high 52 bits of it.)  I don't think most assemblers will let you specify that offset as 0 directly, but you can do it with a label:

```
this_instruction:
    adr x0, this_instruction // x0 <- address of this_instruction
```

The AArch64 stack pointer is called `sp`.  It is not quite a general-purpose register, but can be used like one in a few specific instructions (it is encoded as register 31, which most of the time encodes the zero register `xzr`, but some instructions are special-cased to treat it as `sp` instead).  This includes basic things like `mov`, `add`, and so you can just do `mov x0, sp` to get its current value.

The general-purpose register `x29` is by convention used as a frame pointer when one is needed.  You can retrieve it with `mov x0, x29` or just use `x29` directly as input to any instruction you like.  However, note that "leaf" functions that don't call other functions may not use the frame pointer, in which case `x29` likely points instead to the calling function's stack frame.

---

In general, "translating" x86 code like this, by just looking at one instruction at a time and trying to replace it with an exact ARM equivalent, is unlikely to succeed.  Many aspects of the machines and/or calling conventions don't have direct equivalents.  You really have to step back, figure out what the x86 code as a whole is trying to do, then think about how to produce equivalent behavior on ARM.  So don't work on the level of "this code is accessing eip, what's the equivalent?".  But rather "this code is trying to do a system call / stack unwind / context switch, etc; how does one do that on ARM?"

Comment: Many thanks Nate for your precious infos.   Hum, yes, as I feared, a simple solution like "Google Translate x86 to arm" does not exist yet. ;-( .  And I have to jump much deeper into ARM instructions and go back to my assembly courses.  Anyway, if somebody knows a "more or less" comparable chart of instructions of x86 vs arm, I am interested ( But yes, I understood that it does not have much sense because the architectures are too different ) . Many thanks. Fred